# powershell script to split data in csv cell in row of column one to multiple rows

Tags: powershell

Created a powershell script to extract required data from xml file(Image in Actual Data in excel to Desired output in excel ). Looking to further customize data in each row of column one to multiple rows and copying corresponding same value of col 2,3,4.

Looking for way to perform below steps using powershell

Powershell Script to get Data from XML file to CSV

```
$XmlInfo = @()
```

## Change the file path

[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path Test.xml

$domainids = $XmlDocument.XPS.Policy | Where-Object {$_.class -eq "CA.SM::Domain"} 
  foreach($domainid in $domainids)
  {

```
$OIDs = ($domainid.'#comment' | Select-String CA.SM::Realm | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'Xid="CA.SM::Realm@',''} | Out-String).Trim()
foreach($OID in $OIDs)
  { 
      $obj = New-Object PSObject
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OID -Value ($Relam ID -replace '"','')
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Domain OID -Value ($domainid.Xid | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'CA.SM::Domain@',''} )
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value ($domainid.Property.get(($temp2.Property.name.IndexOf('CA.SM::Domain.Name')))).StringValue
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value ($domainid.Property.get(($temp2.Property.name.IndexOf('CA.SM::Domain.Desc')))).StringValue
      $XmlInfo += $obj
  }
```

}

$XmlInfo | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: please include input and expected output as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where your data is coming from, but here is one way that you could do this:

```
# Get sample data into script
$inputdata = @'
OID,Domain ID,Name,Description
01-123456-7890AB-CDEF 02-123456-7890AB-CDEF 03-123456-7890AB-CDEF 04-123456-7890AB-CDEF,05-111111-22222-3333-4444,Singapore,* Please do not edit this domain!
06-123456-7890AB-CDEF 07-123456-7890AB-CDEF 08-123456-7890AB-CDEF,10-111111-22222-3333-4444,Test,* Please do not edit this domain!
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Show the input data in table format at the powershell prompt
$inputdata | ft -AutoSize

# Initialize $outputdata as array
$outputdata = @()

# Loop through input rows
foreach ($inputrow in $inputdata) {

    # Split line OIDs with "space" as delimiter. Change below as required.
    # For Example, if newline character then replace " " with "`n". If newline then space then "`n " etc.
    $inputOIDs = $inputrow.OID -split " "
    $inputOID = $inputOIDs[0]

    # Initialize group of output rows as array
    $outputrows = @()

    # Loop through each OID in an input line
    foreach ($inputOID in $inputOIDs) {

        # Initialize the output row with desired properties
        $outputrow = "" | select OID,'Domain ID',Name,Description

        # Set the data of the output row
        $outputrow.OID = $inputOID
        $outputrow.'Domain ID' = $inputrow.'Domain ID'
        $outputrow.Name = $inputrow.Name
        $outputrow.Description = $inputrow.Description

        # Add the output row to the group of output rows
    $outputrows += $outputrow
    }

    # Add the group of output rows to the output data
    $outputdata += $outputrows
}

# Show the output data in table format at the powershell prompt
$outputdata | ft -AutoSize

# Show the output data in CSV format at the powershell prompt
$outputdata | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

# Export data to a CSV file: uncomment & replace "your path here"
# $outputdata | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "your path here"
```

This will return:

```
OID                                                                                     Domain ID                 Name      Description                      
---                                                                                     ---------                 ----      -----------                      
01-123456-7890AB-CDEF 02-123456-7890AB-CDEF 03-123456-7890AB-CDEF 04-123456-7890AB-CDEF 05-111111-22222-3333-4444 Singapore * Please do not edit this domain!
06-123456-7890AB-CDEF 07-123456-7890AB-CDEF 08-123456-7890AB-CDEF                       10-111111-22222-3333-4444 Test      * Please do not edit this domain!

OID                   Domain ID                 Name      Description                      
---                   ---------                 ----      -----------                      
01-123456-7890AB-CDEF 05-111111-22222-3333-4444 Singapore * Please do not edit this domain!
02-123456-7890AB-CDEF 05-111111-22222-3333-4444 Singapore * Please do not edit this domain!
03-123456-7890AB-CDEF 05-111111-22222-3333-4444 Singapore * Please do not edit this domain!
04-123456-7890AB-CDEF 05-111111-22222-3333-4444 Singapore * Please do not edit this domain!
06-123456-7890AB-CDEF 10-111111-22222-3333-4444 Test      * Please do not edit this domain!
07-123456-7890AB-CDEF 10-111111-22222-3333-4444 Test      * Please do not edit this domain!
08-123456-7890AB-CDEF 10-111111-22222-3333-4444 Test      * Please do not edit this domain!

"OID","Domain ID","Name","Description"
"01-123456-7890AB-CDEF","05-111111-22222-3333-4444","Singapore","* Please do not edit this domain!"
"02-123456-7890AB-CDEF","05-111111-22222-3333-4444","Singapore","* Please do not edit this domain!"
"03-123456-7890AB-CDEF","05-111111-22222-3333-4444","Singapore","* Please do not edit this domain!"
"04-123456-7890AB-CDEF","05-111111-22222-3333-4444","Singapore","* Please do not edit this domain!"
"06-123456-7890AB-CDEF","10-111111-22222-3333-4444","Test","* Please do not edit this domain!"
"07-123456-7890AB-CDEF","10-111111-22222-3333-4444","Test","* Please do not edit this domain!"
"08-123456-7890AB-CDEF","10-111111-22222-3333-4444","Test","* Please do not edit this domain!"
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Regards,
Richard

Comment: Thank You for looking into my Post, My Source is huge XML file, I have managed write Powershell code to get the data from XML(Code is updated in my post). The script is able to pull data into csv file(Image Actual Data in excel) but i am trying to get data into csv as (Image Desired output in excel).

Comment: I am looking for output similar to yours but want it be done with in my code if it is possible

Comment: Thanks Richard, I was able to use your code and get the desired results